# Android ArrayAdapter Style

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

My question is simply how would I changed the background color (or text color) of the first 6 characters of every cell in my listview ?
(the first 6 chars contain the date. Example “Jan 01: Blah blah blah data data… ” )

I have one listview on my page and it gets populated dynamically from a SOAP webservice call

```
        SoapObject oResponse = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        ArrayList<String> oStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < oResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        oStringList.add(oResponse.getProperty(i).toString()); 
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, oStringList ));
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when setting the text of your `TextView`, you'll use a `Spannable` so you can change the color of a span. here's an example setting the foreground color to red for six characters. you'll use this code in getView and tv is the `TextView` for that particular cell.

```
TextView tv = ...
String text = "Jan 01: Blah blah blah data data...";
int startColor = 0;
int endColor = 6;
int color = 0xffff0000;
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), startColor, endColor, 0);
tv.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: wow thanks for the quick reply.  Not sure how the textView would connect (or populate) to the listview ?  I currently populate my listView with lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, zarray));

Answer (score 0):

dldnh's answer is right, but another way would be to have to TextView's next to each other, one for the date and one for your actual text. So something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android/+id="rowLayout" android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android/+id="txtDate" android:text="Jan 01" android:textColor="@color/red" android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android/+id="txtItem" android:text="blah blah blah" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So in your Adapter, override `getView(int position, View v)` (I am pretty sure that's what it was) and you can set the text in there.

Answer (score 0):

In think you should make your own `ArrayAdapter` layout.

In this new layout, each data of listview has two part: (two textview) and you put it in `horizontal linearlayout`. first textview, you make its attribute like what you say.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple solution for this. Just write down code to change the color for a block of text in html. some thing like

```
String s = "<text color=red>abcdef</text>"+"continuition part will be placed here";

TextView Object.setText(Html.toHtml(s));
```

I don't know the exact code in Html to change the text color exactly. Just google it.

This will solve your issue.